# Psycopg2 UNICODEARRAY

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='my_database_name', ...)
cur = conn.cursor()

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE, conn)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY, conn)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t0;")
res = cur.fetchall()

print conn.encoding
print res
print res[0][0] # Output is true
print [res[0][0]]
```

But out put is:

```
UTF8
[(u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413')]
АБ
[u'\u0410\u0411']
```

Why only third row is true? How to change u'\u***' on the letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is simply the way Python 2 prints unicode types, and is one of the reasons why Python 3 was created in 2008.

In Python 2

```
$ python2
>>> s = u'АБ'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print(s)
АБ
>>> print([s])
[u'\u0410\u0411']
```

But in Python 3

```
$ python3
>>> s = u'АБ'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>    
>>> print(s)
АБ
>>> print([s])
['АБ']
```

The simplest answer to your question "how to make printing of an array of strings better" would be "Use Python 3!"

However, you may, unfortunately be stuck with Python 2 (sorry if this is the case). If you are stuck with Python 2, you could fake it with:

```
$ python2
>>> s = u'АБ'
>>> print([s])
[u'\u0410\u0411']
>>> print('[' + ''.join(s) + ']')
[АБ]
```

It's not pretty but it works. Hopefully you are able to switch to Python 3. (Or maybe others will have a better answer for Python 2 than this hack.)